# Auto restart debugger in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have go application with hot reload, but when I change source code, debug session stops because hot realod rebuild application, and I must restart my debug session manualy.
Can I set some parameter in launch.json which will restart debugger again after some time?

My launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "feedfans-bot",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "attach",
            "mode": "remote",
            "substitutePath": [
                {
                    "from": "${workspaceFolder}/feedfans-bot",
                    "to": "/feedfans-bot",
                },
            ],
            "port": 2345,
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "showLog": false,
            "apiVersion": 2,
            "trace": "verbose",
        }
    ]
}
```